# How can I generate zeros for missing id values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate an output that fills in missing counts with 0s.

I'm using Oracle SQL. So far, my solution is based on [Grouping records hour by hour or day by day and filling gaps with zero or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798905/grouping-records-hour-by-hour-or-day-by-day-and-filling-gaps-with-zero-or-null) with small additions.

```
WITH TEMP
     AS ( SELECT MINDT + ( (LEVEL - 1) / 24) DDD
               FROM (SELECT TRUNC (MIN (MY_TIMESTAMP), 'HH24') MINDT,
                            TRUNC (MAX (MY_TIMESTAMP), 'HH24') MAXDT
                       FROM MAIN_TABLE.TABLE_VIEW THV
                      WHERE MY_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE ('08/01/2018:00:00:00',
                                                           'MM/DD/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                                                    AND TO_DATE (
                                                           '08/03/2018:23:59:59',
                                                           'MM/DD/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')) V
         CONNECT BY MINDT + ( (LEVEL - 1) / 24) <= MAXDT)
  SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (D1, 'HH24'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'), COUNT (D2), ID
    FROM (SELECT NVL (MY_TIMESTAMP, DDD) D1,
                 MY_TIMESTAMP D2,
                 THV.ID ID
            FROM MAIN_TABLE.TABLE_VIEW THV
                 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                    (SELECT DDD FROM TEMP) AD
                 ON DDD = TRUNC (MY_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24')
           WHERE MY_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE ('08/01/2018:00:00:00',
                                                      'MM/DD/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                                         AND TO_DATE ('08/03/2018:23:59:59',
                                                      'MM/DD/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
GROUP BY ID, TRUNC (D1, 'HH24')
ORDER BY ID, TRUNC (D1, 'HH24')
```

Right now I'm getting:

```
CNT   ID        DT
4     1         2018-08-01 00
1     1         2018-08-01 01
1     1         2018-08-01 04
20    1         2018-08-01 05
76    1         2018-08-01 07
```

But what I want is:

```
CNT   ID        DT
4     1         2018-08-01 00
1     1         2018-08-01 01
0     1         2018-08-01 02
0     1         2018-08-01 03
1     1         2018-08-01 04
20    1         2018-08-01 05
0     1         2018-08-01 06
76    1         2018-08-01 07
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `NVL(ID,0)` ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

It works pretty smooth if you have a table to join with that has all the hours you expect to have in the results.  For a table to have all the hours, it would just have 24 records.

It can be a temp table, but if it was a real table, it would simplify your report to a standard query.  And if this report is used regularly, why not have an extra table?  I've seen DBAs have a generic "numbers" table with lots of numbers in it for tricks like this (to get 0-23, query the table `where n between 0 and 23`).  Another example, if you want every individual date for a 90 day period, can use a numbers table for 0-89 and add that value to a start date to be able to join on every possible date in that period.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!